# Selenium error - couldn't register this node: hub down or not responding

Tags: selenium-grid

I'm getting this error message: `couldn't register this node: hub down or not responding.` when I'm trying to follow this quickstart guide:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

When I run the command below:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

I download 2.17.0 version of selenium standalone jar...

I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: 1) What command are you using to start your server hub with? 2) You say you are using 2.17.0 but your command points out 2.14.0; ideally you'll use the same jar for starting the server and client nodes. 3) Try using "-role webdriver" in your client connection string

Answer (score 5):

First, start selenium-grid hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub -timeout 30 -browserTimeout 60
```

After that your node(s):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="pathToIEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="pathToChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe" -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=11,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=chrome,version=latest,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=firefox,version=25,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
```

Some parameters can be changed in last command line, just decide what browser you have, version etc...

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me.

**  For Hub/Master, use this command:

```
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

** For Node/Slave, use this command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/Users/NaveenKhunteta/Downloads/chromedriver" -jar 
        selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node -hub 
        http://192.168.0.102:4444/grid/register
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try to assign the node with port no as follows

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role webdriver -hub ttp://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 7777