# The hub is down or not responding: Unexpected char 0x131 at 23 in User-Agent value: selenium/3.14.0 (java w²ndows) with SeleniumGrid v3.14.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I have selenium standalone server 3.14.0 and want to run hub and then register nodes on it. I first run hub like

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub
```

and it works very well and waits nodes to be registered. And then I run this commands to register a node,

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/register/grid -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS
```

but it constantly keeps giving me this error and I cannot register any node.

```
11:30:47.634 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Unexpected char 0x131 at 23 in User-Agent value: selenium/3.14.0 (java w²ndows)
```

How can I solve this problem?

- I have latest version of chrome driver.

Comment: Possibly duplicate issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945719/selenium-error-couldnt-register-this-node-hub-down-or-not-responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
[SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Unexpected char 0x131 at 23 in User-Agent value: selenium/3.14.0 (java w²ndows)
```

...implies that the *Selenium Grid Node* wasn't registered to the *Selenium Grid Hub*.

Your main issue is your underlying **Operating System** is not in **English**.

### Solution

Try the same in an **English** version of an *Operating System* the commands will work without any problem.

- You can find a relevant discussion in [Selenium UnreachableBrowserException - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962953/selenium-unreachablebrowserexception-java)
- tl;dr

  - [okhttp3 User-Agent Unexpected char exception](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2331)
  - [IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char ... in header value: ... at com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue (Headers.java:295)](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2016)

---

Apart from that, I don't see any such issues with your commands.

Your command to start the **Selenium Grid Hub** is perfect:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub
```

You should see the following startup logs:

```
C:\Utility\SeleniumGrid>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub
14:31:09.654 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0'
14:31:09.659 INFO [GridLauncherV3$2.launch] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
2018-10-02 14:31:10.381:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1570ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
14:31:11.086 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
14:31:11.087 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://192.168.1.5:4444/grid/register/
14:31:11.088 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://192.168.1.5:4444/wd/hub
```

Your command to start the **Selenium Grid Node** is also perfect:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/register/grid -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS
```

You should see the following startup logs:

```
C:\Utility\SeleniumGrid>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/register/grid -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS
14:38:06.877 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0'
14:38:06.904 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Launching a Selenium Grid node onport 27852
2018-10-02 14:38:07.459:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1105ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
14:38:07.829 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 27852
14:38:07.830 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
14:38:08.069 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
14:38:08.070 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
14:38:09.108 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

The **Grid Console** at `http://localhost:4444/grid/console` will look like:

[image: GridConsole]